# JSON to CSV / How to fix _csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType

Tags: python, json, csv

Have written some code to take a directory full of JSON files and create a new CSV that shows all of their data in one place. I think I am almost there, but get this error at the very end:

```
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not NoneType
```

All the JSON files look like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ticker": "NDX",
      "tradeDate": "2017-01-03",
      "expirDate": "2017-01-06",
      "dte": 4,
      "strike": 3300,
      "stockPrice": 4900.5,
      "callVolume": 0,
      "callOpenInterest": 0,
      "callBidSize": 10,
      "callAskSize": 1,
      "putVolume": 0,
      "putOpenInterest": 0,
      "putBidSize": 0,
      "putAskSize": 2,
      "callBidPrice": 1593.1,
      "callValue": 1600.64,
      "callAskPrice": 1607.5,
      "putBidPrice": 0,
      "putValue": 0,
      "putAskPrice": 2.2,
      "callBidIv": 0,
      "callMidIv": 2.190066,
      "callAskIv": 2.190066,
      "smvVol": 0.160588,
      "putBidIv": 0,
      "putMidIv": 1.866392,
      "putAskIv": 1.866392,
      "residualRate": 0,
      "delta": 1,
      "gamma": -3.01422e-15,
      "theta": -0.0470117,
      "vega": 9.14631e-11,
      "rho": 0.2721,
      "phi": -0.404087,
      "driftlessTheta": -2.29457e-8,
      "extSmvVol": 0.242996,
      "extCallValue": 1600.5,
      "extPutValue": 0,
      "spotPrice": 4900.51,
      "updatedAt": "2019-04-02 10:27:11"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the code (the sample JSON file that I'm using to define the list of fields to process is just called 'out', and is in the folder above 'options'). Output.csv (destination file) is also in the folder above 'options':

```
def get_list_of_json_files():

    list_of_files = os.listdir('options')

    return list_of_files

def create_list_from_json(out):

    with open(out) as f:

        data = json.load(f)

    data_list = []

    data_list.append(data["data"][0]["ticker"])

    data_list.append(data["data"][0]["other fields"])

def write_csv():

    list_of_files = get_list_of_json_files()

    for file in list_of_files:

        row = create_list_from_json(f'options/{file}')

        with open('output.csv', 'a') as c:

            writer = csv.writer(c)

            writer.writerow(row)

        c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    write_csv()
```

Comment: full error should show you which line of code make problem so use `print()` to check values in variables in this line.

Comment: you forgot `return data_list` in `create_list_from_json` so it returns `None` and you have `row = None` and it makes your problem when you run `writer.writerow(row)` because you have `writer.writerow(None)`.

Comment: thank you so much, that did fix an error and led to an actual output being created!!

Comment: however I am getting only one row of data per file to be written...whereas each json file should result in ~300 rows at a minimum. do you know what I am missing?